# FFmpeg: Images to video, repeat x times

Tags: image, ffmpeg, sequence, repeat

I convert a list of images to a video with ffmpeg.

But I want a video which repeat all the images x times without storing copies of the images on the harddrive.

Is there a way to tell ffmpeg to repeat the input images in a video x times?

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop 2 -i img%d.jpg -vf setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB x3.mp4
```

to have three loops of the sequence - first run + two repeats.